# Google assistant input limited to dropdown options picked from excel

Tags: google-sheets, actions-on-google

I would like to log my food items when i eat them through google assistant. Aim: to quickly log all items in my meal [all items predefined in a sheet, google assistant has to recognize item from only the item-list column and log it]. Final action = sum of calories[next column to items] of items had is reported and logged as well. A report like

"item 1,2,3 had for lunch/dinner on this day. total calorie consumed= X"

this log automatically stored in google sheets row-wise

Answer (score 1):

Building an [Action](https://actions.google.com) using [Dialogflow](http://dialogflow.com), you can create [entities](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities) which are a fixed set of values. When you create an [Intent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents), you can limit training phrases to only accept user queries that are of the given type.

[image]

After this intent is triggered, you'll want to setup a [webhook](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment). This will be some code that will receive the parameter and do something with it. In your case, it will use the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/) to write a new row.

Comment: Thank you. This gives alot of clarity to start, I'll try something.